# find out object item names in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

let's say you're passing an object to a function

```
{title:"my title", data:"corresponding data"}
```

how can I get the function to know what the names of the items/sub-objects are (`title` and `data`) without specifying them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop as follows:

```
for (var key:String in obj) {
    var value:String = obj[key];
    trace(key + ": " + value);
}
```

Or use the introspection API.

The Flex 3 Help page on [Performing Object Introspection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=usingas_8.html) has a good overview of these.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for(String in Object)` loop like so:

```
var i:String;
for(i in object)
{
    var key:String = i;
    var value:Object = object[i];

    // do stuff with key/value
}
```

PS it would make more sense obviously to use `key` in the loop, my example is done for the sake of **demonstration**.

---

Why was this downvoted.. Because I didn't do a function?

```
function findKeys(obj:Object):Array
{
    var ar:Array = [];

    var i:String;
    for(i in obj)
    {
        ar.push(i);
    }

    return ar;
}

var ob:Object = {things:"value", other:5};

trace(findKeys(ob)); // other,things
```